# Lambda - Question regarding BigInteger and Lambda Usage in this specific application

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, biginteger

[BigInteger_Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y3sr.png/)

[Sample_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmY0i.png/)

Given the following interface class

```
interface BigOperation
{
    public BigInteger operation (Biglnteger x, Biglnteger y);
}
```

Write Lambda expressions to implement BigOperation to simulate three arithmetic operations
/ and % on Biglnteger. You can call them op1, op2 and op3 respectively. Note that the three
operations in Biglnteger are called multiply, divide and remainder respectively.
Using these three operations, we wish to multiply all the digits in a Biglnteger. For example, if the
Biglnteger is 234, the product is 2 * 3 * 4 = 24. The method has the following method heading:

```
static Biglnteger product (BigInteger n, BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2,
BigOperation op3)
```

Compare the implementation of this method using two approaches: Iterative and Recursive.
Put the Lambda expressions in a main method. Construct a few Biglnteger objects, invoke the
methods to test our design. The following shows some of the sample outputs:

```
Given big integer 8584803
(Iterative) e
(Recursive) 0
Given big integer 12345
(Iterative) 120
(Recursive) 120
```

I have no idea how to proceed with the code after what I have as attached. I wanted to try looping through the `BigInteger N` with a *foreach* but it doesn't seem to work. Next, I wanted to do a `for(int i = 0)`, etc. loop but I do not know how to get location reference to a `BigInteger` variable. I don't know how to use lambda for this.

Thanks in advance for answering my queries.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

interface BigOperation{
    public BigInteger operation(BigInteger x,BigInteger y);
}

class LearningBigInteger {
    static BigInteger product(BigInteger n,BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2, BigOperation op3){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigOperation multiply = BigInteger::multiply;
        BigOperation divide = BigInteger::divide;
        BigOperation remainder = BigInteger::remainder;
        Random r = new Random();
        BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(r.nextInt()));
        BigInteger m = product(n,multiply,divide,remainder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bryead - I understand that you are asking about homework, and provide a couple of screenshots of the statement & example output. Copying the *relevant* parts of the text of those screenshots would make your answer much easier to answer - which is would be a win for you: more & better answers.

Comment: hi @tucuxi, I have edited the question to include the text of the screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
interface BigOperation {
    BigInteger operation(BigInteger x, BigInteger y);
}

static class Iterative {
    static BigInteger product(BigInteger x, BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2, BigOperation op3) {
        BigInteger product = BigInteger.ONE;
        for ( ; x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; x = op2.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN))
            product = op1.operation(product, op3.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN));
        return product;
    }
}

static class Recursive {
    static BigInteger product(BigInteger x, BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2, BigOperation op3) {
        if (x.compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) < 0)
            return x;
        else
            return op1.operation(op3.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN),
                product(op2.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN), op1, op2, op3));
    }
}
```

and

```
static void test(BigInteger x, BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2, BigOperation op3) {
    System.out.println("Given bit integer " + x);
    System.out.println("(Iterative) " + Iterative.product(x, op1, op2, op3));
    System.out.println("(Recursive) " + Recursive.product(x, op1, op2, op3));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigOperation multiply = BigInteger::multiply;
    BigOperation divide = BigInteger::divide;
    BigOperation remainder = BigInteger::remainder;
    test(new BigInteger("8584803"), multiply, divide, remainder);
    test(new BigInteger("12345"), multiply, divide, remainder);
}
```

output:

```
Given bit integer 8584803
(Iterative) 0
(Recursive) 0
Given bit integer 12345
(Iterative) 120
(Recursive) 120
```

Comment: thanks for helping out. I have a small question about the iterative class, how does the for-loop works? 
I have yet to see a for-loop without a starting statement.

Answer (score 3):

First the code. Explanations appear after the code.

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class LearningBigInteger {
    private static BigOperation multiply;
    private static BigOperation divide;
    private static BigOperation remainder;

    private static BigInteger digitProduct(BigInteger x) {
        if (x.compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) <= 0) {
            return x;
        }
        else {
            BigInteger r = remainder.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN);
            BigInteger newX = divide.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN);
            return multiply.operation(r, digitProduct(newX));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        multiply = (x, y) -> x.multiply(y);
        divide = (x, y) -> x.divide(y);
        remainder = (x, y) -> x.remainder(y);
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("8584803");
        BigInteger product = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (x.compareTo(BigInteger.TEN) >= 0) {
            BigInteger r = remainder.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN);
            product = multiply.operation(product, r);
            x = divide.operation(x, BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        System.out.println(product);
        System.out.println(digitProduct(new BigInteger("12345")));
    }
}

interface BigOperation {
    public BigInteger operation(BigInteger x,BigInteger y);
}
```

Interface `BigOperation` is referred to as a *functional interface* because it contains exactly one [abstract] method.

A lambda expression is a shorthand way of writing an implementation of the sole method in a functional interface.

The way to write a lambda expression is to first write the list of parameters for the method, followed by the arrow symbol and finally followed by the method body. The syntax varies slightly depending on the number of method parameters and the number of lines in the method body. In the above code, the syntax is for a method with two parameters and the method body is just one line. The syntax would be different if either there was just one method parameter or if there were more than one line in the method body.

The code in your question uses [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) which, I suppose, are a special form of [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

In the above code, method `main` contains the iterative approach while method `digitProduct` implements the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

```java
class LearningBigInteger {
    // Iterable version
    static BigInteger product(BigInteger n, BigOperation... ops) {
        BigInteger temp = n;

        for (BigOperation op : ops) {
            // I only have temp to work it
            // so it is being processed
            // to itself, pointless i know!
            temp = op.operation(temp, temp);
        }

        return temp;
    }

    // Discrete version
    static BigInteger product(BigInteger n,BigOperation op1, BigOperation op2, BigOperation op3){
        BigInteger temp = n;

        // This layout is good
        // if you keep the same temp
        // variable as input!
        temp = op1.operation(temp, temp);
        temp = op2.operation(temp, temp);
        temp = op3.operation(temp, temp);

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Also I can't open the links you provided. Notify me when fixed!

Comment: added the text in the links as part of the question.